# Website dataset with their types

Tags: dataset

Does any body know of any dataset of websites tagged by the verticals they are working or their types.
For ex. Amazon.com: ecommerce, fb.com: social networking etc

I want to cluster websites which are similar in terms of their verticals. I was looking for tagged dataset to achieve that. Any other approach is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of sites which provide about the information you are looking for. Because of your approach of tagging websites with different categories, I would recommend this site.

You may wanna look into "Audience Interests" > "Categories" or "Topics":
https://www.similarweb.com/website/amazon.com#alsoVisited